# Continuous Deployment not working

Tags: amazon-s3, circleci

I need to continually build a [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) application and deploy it to Amazon S3 bucket.

I have written the following CircleCi `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
deployment:
  prod:
    branch: circle-config-test
    commands: 
      - aws s3 sync build/ s3://http://www.typing-coacher.net.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ --delete
```

*What I think should happens:*

1. I have a docker container, I install the application, build it and the files are resting ready in `build` folder.
2. I am [running the command](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-amazon-s3/) listed in CircleCi docs and the build files are moving from the docker machine to s3 bucket.

> To deploy a project to S3, you can use the following command in the
>   deployment section of circle.yml:
>
> `aws s3 sync <path-to-files> s3://<bucket-URL> --delete`

*What actually happens:*

Application is being install and build files are being created, but nothing happen with deployment. it doesn't even appear on the builds console.

What Am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*disclaimer: CircleCI Developer Advocate*

Everything from the `deployment:` line and down shouldn't be there. That's syntax for CircleCI 1.0 while the rest of your config file is CircleCI 2.0.

You can either:

1. Create a new step and check for the branch name with Bash. If it's `circle-config-test`, then run the deployment commands. You'll also need to install the AWS CLI in that build.
2. Using [CircleCI Workflows], create a deployment job with a branch filter for `circle-config-test`. You can use any image that contains the AWS CLI or install it yourself. The [CI Builds: AWS](https://hub.docker.com/r/cibuilds/aws) Docker image contains this for you.